# How to add a second optional object to open Outlook in Access VBA?

Tags: vba, class, object, ms-access, set

So far I have the first referral open-up the Outlook and retrieving the right email address with an automatic customized message. Now, I'm trying to add a second referral, `Referral_To_ID_2` as an optional, meaning don't raise error if it isn't selected. Below is the form and the code I have so far, but I'm not quite sure if I'm doing it right by assigning a reference to my second object, `Referral_To_ID_2` as well as the `If` statement. Now it's actually giving me an error if I don't select anything in `Referral_To_ID_2` Can anyone explain me the best way to add a second object as an optional? Many thanks!

[image]

```
Private Sub cmdReferralEmail_Click()

Dim emailAddresses As Collection, newEmail As Email
Dim emailAddresses2 As Collection, newEmail2 As Email

Set emailAddresses = GetEmails(referralId:=Referral_To_ID)
Set emailAddresses2 = GetEmails(referralId:=Referral_To_ID_2)

If emailAddresses Is Nothing Then 'User cancelled
ElseIf emailAddresses2 Is Nothing Then 'User cancelled
    GoTo ExitHandler
ElseIf emailAddresses.count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No email addresses were selected for this client.", vbExclamation
Else
    Set newEmail = New Email
    Set newEmail2 = New Email
    With newEmail
        .HtmlBody = _
            "<p>We referred a potential client to you, " & _
            Nz(First_Name & " ", "") & Nz(Last_Name, "") & _
            ", who needs help with an employment matter in " & Nz(State, "your state") & _
            ".  Thank you for any assistance you might be able to provide.</p>"
        Set .MailTo = emailAddresses
        Set .MailTo = emailAddresses2
        .Cc.Add "kjghkjgh@ihiu.com"
        .Subject = "Potential"
        .Send
    End With
End If End Sub
```

Comment: Could it be because you're trying to `Set .MailTo = emailAddresses2` when there actually isn't an email?  What is the error message?  Secondly, at the top when you `Set emailAddresses2 = ...` shouldn't you use `ID_2` at the end?  And why can't you use an `IF` statement to say `IF referral 2 not null, then` concatenate your email addresses so you only add one big one?  That's how I set mine.  Loop and concatenate until `EOF`

Comment: @TKEyi60 Yes, you're right! I forgot to look my code carefully and added those you mentioned. The error message is going to Set emailAddresses2 = GetEmails(referralId:=Referral_To_ID_2) telling that there's no user input. Also I like your suggestion about concatenating email which I think is the most important part of this. Can you please hint some more on it? Maybe coding syntax? I'm so new to VBA. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I would like to apologize, because I cannot figure out how to concatenate multiple email addresses.  I looked back at old code I had written and I'll post below.  See if that helps.  And sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My program reads through a list of people, if they are marked for a Maintenance for example it pulls a query and sets a recordset to that query with:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Email FROM Employees WHERE '" & department & "' = Department"
Debug.Print strSQL 'I do this so I can see what my query is in the immediate window
Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Then when the recordset has been made, I loop through each record that matched the criteria in the query and add the to the `olTo` of the email.

```
Do While Not myR.EOF
    Debug.Print myR!Email 'print the email of the record I'm on
    Set appOutlookRec = .Recipients.Add(myR!Email)
    appOutlookRec.Type = olTo
    myR.MoveNext
Loop
```

But to answer your question more specifically, I would add two `IF` statements checking first if `Referral_To_ID_2` is null.

```
If Referral_To_ID_2 = Null Then 'or if its a string then If Len(Me.Notes & vbNullString) = 0
    'do nothing
Else
    Set emailAddresses2 = GetEmails(referralId:=Referral_To_ID_2)
End if
```

then put the second if down where you `Set .MailTo`

```
If emailAddresses2 = Nothing then 'I think that's how that would go, not 100%
    'do nothing
Else
     Set .MailTo = emailAddresses2
End if
```

No please know that I'm no guru.  I've tried to piece this together with my knowledge I've picked up on so if anyone reads this and can modify it better then have at it.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this and let you know!

Comment: your input definitely helped me, so here's what I have that works: `If IsNull(Referral_To_ID_2) Then
        On Error Resume Next
    Else
        Set emailAddresses2 = GetEmails(referralId:=Referral_To_ID_2)
    End If`

Answer (score 0):

Because I needed it to open two separate Outlook windows I had to basically copy and paste the code I had for the second referral from the first referral and for the second referral not show error when isn't selected, here is what I came up with and it's working:

`If IsNull(Referral_To_ID_2) Then
        On Error Resume Next
    Else
        Set emailAddresses2 = GetEmails(referralId:=Referral_To_ID_2)
    End If`

Thanks all for your input!